# Investigate and if possible determine the value of the integrals

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

Investigate the existence and, if possible, determine the value of the integrals below:

$\int_{[0,1]^2}f(x,y) d(x,y)$, $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y) dx dy$, $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y) dy dx$

where $f(x,y) = \frac{x^2 - \frac{1}{3}}{y^2}$.

If computed the second integral: $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y) dx dy$, which is $0$, and the third: $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y) dy dx$ which is $\infty$, if I'm correct. But I dont know how to calculate the first one. Could somebody help me please?

Comment: Hint: which theorem does this situation make you think of? And what would it tell you?

Comment: Well all I could think is maybe Tonelli or Fubini but the thing is that I just started to learn these stuff and can't actually work on that despite the hints. I saw some examples dividing f into 2 parts: f= f+ - f-, but thats all I can think of unfortunately

Comment: Yeah that's the ones. Fubini tells you that if the first integral were finite, then all three integrals would be equal, but I guess you are not allowed to use it yet?